# Java ASCII encoding

Tags: java, ascii

I have a quick question relating to ASCII and encoding. I am looking to take the input from a user - for example: "cat" - and turn it into a code. The code is as follows:

1. All lower case letters are converted to capital letters.
2. The first letter in the encoded message is stored as it's ASCII code value.
3. All subsequent letters are represented as the offset between the current letter and the previous letter.

For example: "cat" = 67 -2 19 since "C" = 67, "A" is -2 letters away from "C", and "T" is 19 letters away from "A". Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you actually tried anything?

Comment: What have you tried? Hint, look at methods in the [`Character`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String s = input.next().toUpperCase();
int ascii = s.charAt(0);
System.out.println(ascii);
for (int i = 1; i < s.length(); i++) {
    ascii = s.charAt(i - 1);
    System.out.println(s.charAt(i) - ascii);
}
```

1. To convert to capital letters there is the toUpperCase() method which returns the string with all capital letters.
2. To get the ASCII code of a letter you can simply create an integer and assign it the desired character (in this case the first letter of the string, so `int ascii = s.charAt(0);`).
3. To get the offsets you can use a for-loop starting from 1 (the second letter) where you get the ASCII code of the previous character and subtract it from the current one.

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Comment: @Tolen You noticed that your result doesn't match OPs expectations, right?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I greatly appreciate it! My only question is - what would I do for the return value if I made this into it's own method?

Comment: @JakePetersen you could use an int array: instead of printing the value you store it in the array and then return it